# Fiware Cosmos Hive connection with Python

Tags: fiware, fiware-cosmos

I´m trying to send Hive queries to Fiware Cosmos using the following Python code:

```
with pyhs2.connect(host='cosmos.lab.fiware.org',port=10000,
                                                authMechanism="PLAIN",
                                                user='xxx',
                                                password="xxx",
                                                database ="xxx" ) as conn: 

                    print ("pyhs --- %s seconds ---" % ( time.time() - start_time))
                    with conn.cursor() as cur:
                            print ("conn ok --- %s seconds ---" % ( time.time() - start_time))
                            cur.execute("add JAR /usr/local/apache-hive-0.13.0-bin/lib/json-serde-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar")
```

but i get the following error:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
File "script2.py", line 40, in <module>
database ="default" ) as conn: 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhs2/__init__.py", line 7, in connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhs2/connections.py", line 46, in __init__
transport.open() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhs2/cloudera/thrift_sasl.py", line 74, in open
status, payload = self._recv_sasl_message()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhs2/cloudera/thrift_sasl.py", line 92, in _recv_sasl_message
header = self._trans.readAll(5)
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 58, in readAll
chunk = self.read(sz - have)
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 105, in read
buff = self.handle.recv(sz)
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Two months ago I could connect with the same code. Any changes or solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `cosmos.lab.fiware.org` is in process of being disconnected from FIWARE Lab. This was announced by a massive notification to all FIWARE users. Currentñy, it already exists as a backup for the data stored, but not working as a service anymore. Please check the [FIWARE catalogue](http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/bigdata-analysis-cosmos/instances) for the new Cosmos instance replacing the old one.